# C++ compiler flag to ignore warnings for external libraries but without including directory

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, clang

There are two ways, as far as I can tell, to ignore warnings for external libraries.

First way is to use `#pragma`:

```
#pragma gcc diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
```

Second way is to add `-isystem/path/to/system/lib` to the compiler flags. This labels that particular include path as an external include path, and so the compiler will not emit warnings stemming from those includes.

I have a large project with many compilation targets, some of which use particular third party libraries which cause problems for my compiler. For reasons I cannot use the `#pragma` option.

But if I use the `-isystem` as a blanket compiler flag for all build targets, then I will unfortunately include `/path/to/system/lib` for every other build target, even those which do not use that system library. This means other targets will search through those external libraries, which is not desirable.

Is there a compiler option, similar to `-isystem` which can be added in a blanket way, which *does not add to the search path*, but only excludes warnings if the path happens to already be included in the search path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a large project with many compilation targets, some of which use particular third party libraries which cause problems for my compiler. For reasons I cannot use the `#pragma` option.

Can you elaborate on this?  Why is a wrapper header with `#pragma GCC diagnostic` not an option?  That is, something like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#include </path/to/real/include.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

(Or if you want to get fancy, use `#include_next`.)  You would apply this only when crossing subsystem boundaries; the subsystem itself would be compiled with `-Wunused-parameter`.

I don't see anything in the GCC/libcpp sources which would allow one to reset the system header flag without adding a new system header.  In any case, this looks to me like something which could be reasonably addressed within the build system.

Comment: I work with an existing codebase at an organization and have to obey the senior code reviewers, who specify that I cannot use the pragma solution.

Comment: I can do some fiddly CMake sorcery to correctly set `-isystem` only for relevant targets, but it would be a more time-consuming solution than having a flag that does exactly what I need. I am almost done with doing the fiddly CMake sorcery though, so it should be OK if there isn't such a flag...